# Age comparison from Scanner input using else if

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I am just learning to code at University now. We were given a task to create an else if program based on the scanner that takes the users age as input. I have encountered an issue where only one output shows, regardless of the input. Can anyone help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorldApp {
 static public void main(String[] args) {


     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int age;

        System.out.println("Enter your age");
        age = input.nextInt();

        if (age <= 18) { 
        System.out.println("You are a child!");

        }

        else if (age < 59 && age > 19) {
        System.out.println("You are an adult!"); 
        }

        else if (age >= 60); {

        System.out.println("You are old!");

        }
     }
 }
```

This seems to print out the `You are old` option every time you input age.

Comment: Note that 19-year-old users don't see a message. Replace `> 19` with `>= 19` to fix this.

Comment: @MCEmperor Or just remove `&& age > 19`, it's a useless check :)

Comment: @CristianTraìna That's indeed even better :-). This is also true for `else if (age >= 60)`; it could just be replaced with `else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is below bold line.

The semicolon after if block is causing this.

remove the semicolon.

**else if (age >= 60);**

this is making if statement separate from the print line statement.  that's why print line is executing irrespective of what is the input.

Answer (score 1):

After `else` or `else if` or `if` do not put `semicolon` if you have to execute multiple of codes in this statement, so removing the `semicolon` and leaving the `brackets` will solve your problem.

So your code will be :

```
    int age;

    System.out.println("Enter your age");
    age = in.nextInt();

    if (age <= 18) {
        System.out.println("You are a child!");

    }
    else if (age < 59 && age > 19) {
        System.out.println("You are an adult!");
    } 
    else if (age >= 60) {

        System.out.println("You are old!");
    }
```